# python module binaries (pep8.exe) not found in python scripts folder if -t flag used

Tags: python, pip, pep8

If any python package is installed to different target directory using below command

```
pip install pep8 -t c:\external --no-cache-dir
```

then pep8.exe is missing in the c:\Python27\scripts folder. Where will pep8.exe reside in this case?

If I perform normal installation

```
pip install pep8
```

Then I see pep8.exe in C:\Python27\Scripts

OS: Windows 7
Python: 2.7.11

Any Idea where the pip.exe is going, when I use -t flag?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out , below command gets/puts the executable(pep8.exe - binaries/scripts coming as part of installation) into C:\Python27\Scripts

```
pip install pep8 -t c:\external --no-cache-dir --install-option="--install-scripts=C:\Python27\Scripts"
```

This is applicable for all modules installations